# How to troubleshoot leaking memory in Explorer.exe (Win 10 x64 1709)

Tags: windows-10, memory, windows-explorer, memory-leaks, windows-10-v1709

The `explorer.exe` process in my installation of Windows 10 64bit 1709 (`Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.125]`) is leaking memory.

As the time passes both the **Private Bytes** and the **Working Set** is increasing and so far I couldn't find the reason for this.

This has started happening ever since I've upgraded to 1709. At first, I thought it has to do with the upgrade process so I've made a fresh install but it didn't help.

### What I've tried so far

Using `Process Explorer` (from sysinternals) to monitor the behavior of the process, I've decided to try and eliminate the possibility that this is caused by a 3rd party Shell Extension, but unfortunately, it didn't solve the problem.

Please see below the current status of shell extensions:

```
32bit - https://pastebin.com/Pk60YLz1
64bit - https://pastebin.com/81TJJwbd
```

Please see the Process Explorer export TXT:

```
https://pastebin.com/u0JTr2fL
```

Process Explorer screenshot with the `explorer.exe` process Performance properties:

[image: Process Explorer Screenshot 171218]

VirusTotal / Malware / Antivirus software scans comes back clean.

## What's next?

Since disabling the Shell Extensions didn't work, I'm out of ideas how to proceed.

Any advise how to find the problem would be greatly appriciated!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70544/discussion-on-question-by-aternus-how-to-troubleshoot-leaking-memory-in-explorer).